# Images in JFrame don't display

Tags: java, image, swing

I am trying to add images to my program and I have a problem with 2 of them. Ball.png and ground.png don't display.

Where did I make a mistake?

When I add images of ball and ground as a background, there is no problem.

```
    public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

Image ball;
Image ground;
Image arrow;

public Game(){
    try {
        ball = ImageIO.read(new File("ball.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("pliku brak");
    }
    try {
        ground = ImageIO.read(new File("ground.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("pliku brak");
    } 
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(ball, 100, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(ground, 300, 300, null);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            okienko();
        }
    });
}

public static void okienko()
{    

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hold The Ball");

    try
    {
        frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("background.png")))));
    } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("pliku brak");
        }
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new Game());
    frame.setSize(1000, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);       
}
}
```

Comment: 1) `g.drawImage(ball, 100, 100, null);` should be `g.drawImage(ball, 100, 100, this);` 2) `frame.setSize(1000, 600);` instead override the preferred size method of the `Game` panel to return the playing field/game size.  Then `pack()` the frame after it is added.  It will be the exact right size.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to layer components like this.

The best approach here would be to paint the background at the same time as painting the other game elements.  To do that:

1. Change

   ```
   Image arrow;
   ```

   to

   ```
   Image arrow; 
   Image bg; // declare the BG as a class attribute of the Game class
   ```
2. Load the BG at the same time as the other two images.
3. Paint the BG first (at 0x0) in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see your `Game JPanel` because your `JFrame` is filled with the `frame.setContentPane(...)` Background `JLabel`. You need to use a `LayoutManager` to be able to lay your Panel over the other.

```
 frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 frame.add(new Game(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Will fix that.
But then you will not see the Background since your `Game JPanel` is on top of all. To fix that you should make this Panel have an invisible background.
So add

```
setOpaque(false);
```

to your `Game` Constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You should use image path with ImageIcon then setIcon to JLabel.

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/background.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

You can read this :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: Using `ImageIO` is the better way to load images since it gives feedback on failure.